# Laravel Jetstream Login Page - Logo is too big

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

I have being trying to fix this bug for the whole day, where the login, register and dashboard page all look horrific. I can't even begin to explain how ugly the login looks so I have attached a screenshot of it.[image] (my login page on left) (normal login on right)

The most frustrating thing is that my login page also looks normal when I first start a new Laravel project straight after installing Jetstream. But I work on something else and when I come back to the login page it always ends up looking like this. I have even discarded all changes on git to go back to when it looked normal (deleting all of my work) but the login page would still look like this.

If somebody has any idea as to how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated :,)

the code:

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <x-authentication-card>
        <x-slot name="logo">
            <x-authentication-card-logo />
        </x-slot>

        <x-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            @csrf

            <div>
                <x-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
                <x-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autofocus autocomplete="username" />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-label for="password" value="{{ __('Password') }}" />
                <x-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" />
            </div>

            <div class="block mt-4">
                <label for="remember_me" class="flex items-center">
                    <x-checkbox id="remember_me" name="remember" />
                    <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ __('Remember me') }}</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
                    </a>
                @endif

                <x-button class="ml-4">
                    {{ __('Log in') }}
                </x-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </x-authentication-card>
</x-guest-layout>
```

Comment: CSS is not loaded properly. Check that.

Comment: Not only the logo but also the forms.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yeah I realized that but I wasn't sure how to edit the css of this page, the code for the login page is:

Comment: I would assume that this is a fresh install of laravel in localhost where assets are not properly running. Did you run `npm run dev` ?

Comment: sorry I'll put it in the post its too long to put in comments

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS assets are not compiled, you should run:
`npm run build` to compile your assets and this should fix the problem, or `npm run dev` to run it in watch mode; as mentioned by @Mr. Kenneth in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, was able to get it working!